# How to generate Kibana links with Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I would like to write a Java class which generates URLs for Kibana 4.5.4.
For example, I would like to add multiple queries like

```
query:(match:(my_tags:(query:TEST,type:phrase))))
```

and something like

```
_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,value:0),time:(from:now-1y,mode:quick,to:now))
```

The final URL should look like:

```
https://mykibanaserver/kibana/app/kibana/?_g=(...)&_a=(....)
```

Is there any documentation/specification of the URL format or any Java API for this?

Note that I do not want to make a REST call but generate the URL as string!

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation for Kibana URL, and no API. 
To perform the build of our URLs, we make some POJO for G and A wich contain the diferents properties as attriutes of the class.
Then you can build the URL with it.